# emerged relatively unscathed 1/

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "1/" stand for?

> The New York Times liked
> Amy Julia Harris tweeted

NEW INVESTIGATION: Victor Rivera built an empire by housing homeless people in New York City. Despite a decade of allegations of sexual and financial abuse, he has **emerged relatively unscathed 1/**

Comment: Well, what did they tweet next?

Comment: I guessed that too. But the next tweet was without "2/": UPDATE: Mayor Bill de Blasio ordered a review of the groups that run New York’s homeless housing after our 
@NYTMetro
 story uncovered accusations of sexual and financial misconduct by one of the city's top shelter operators.

Comment: Usually, it's *1/n* where *n* is the total number of tweets to come in this series. Quite possibly, they didn't know exactly how many were coming but knew there was at least one more (so it's like a "Stay tuned"). (Twitter has a character limit, so tweeting large chunks requires splitting them up into many tweets.) Based on your recent comment, two was all there was to come (since they ended the enumeration).

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty clear that this case is an example of shorthand for "Item number 1 of "  whether or not there is actually a further item.

From the length and content, we can surmise that this was a tweet, so it is possible that a follow-on tweet was either never published, deleted later, or even just a glitch in automatic software.

Originally, this abbreviation will have come from "Page 1 of 2"  etc. in written materials, where it is used as an explicit warning that the document is supposed to have further pages, and might be written as "1/ "  for longish typewritten documents when the actual length is not known at the time of writing.